# Property file resolution in ${catalina.base}/lib subdirectory

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, tomcat7

I have a Tomcat 7(.0.42) instance, which has lib/hosts directory in it (in ${catalina.base} to be more specific), with multiple host-specific properties (say qa1.properties, qa2.properties and so on).

When trying to load a property file, which uses:

```
applicationContext.getResource("classpath:hosts/qa1.properties").exists()
```

it fails, because *exists()* returns *false*. The file is obviously in *hosts* subdirectory. If the file is copied/moved to *lib* directory, it works fine by invoking similar code:

```
applicationContext.getResource("classpath:qa1.properties").exists()
```

Spring's implementation class *ClassPathResource* is used here, which invokes

```
return this.classLoader.getResource("hosts/qa1.properties");
```

and classloader instance is *org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader*

According to Spring specification, location can specify subdirectories (like *classpath:/path/to/file*). How come it is not working here?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that *hosts* subdirectory was missing +x permission.